# Start DRb service then fork and communicate via service - Why doesn't this work?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking to create an `isolate!` method for our tests to isolate global state changes in tests. We're using Minitest as our test suite. My current approach is to start up DRb with the current minitest reporter, fork, and then pass the results back to the main process via DRb.

This is what I have right now:

```
module ForkingRunner
  require 'drb'

  def run(reporter, options = {})
    with_drb_reporter(reporter) do |_reporter|
      super _reporter, options
      puts _reporter.reporters.first.count
    end
  end

  private

  def drb_path
    "drbunix:#{Rails.root.join('tmp/minitest-fork')}"
  end

  def with_drb_reporter(reporter)
    DRb.start_service drb_path, reporter
    pid = fork do
      yield DRbObject.new_with_uri(drb_path)
    end
    Process.wait pid
    puts reporter.reporters.first.count
  ensure
    DRb.stop_service
  end
end

ActiveSupport::TestCase.class_eval do
  def self.isolate!
    singleton_class.prepend ForkingRunner
  end
end
```

Note that the reporter's test count is valid after I `super` in `run` in my forked process, but the reporter's test count is still 0 when queried from my main process after the fork returns in `with_drb_reporter`.

Any ideas why this doesn't work? I'm fairly new to DRb, so maybe it's some quirk with that. Does it have to do with copy-on-write screwing up my DRb connection?